# Multiple parameters in Form->postLink at CakePHP 2.3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Is it possible to pass multiple parameters to an action in the controller by using the method `postLink` of the `FormHelper`?

I didn't manage to do it by using the `options` array. It is not very well specified in the docs what values this array admits.

This is what I tryed:

```
$this->Form->postLink($staffUser['User']['_name'], array(
           'action' => 'subscribe', 
           array('ticketId' => $ticket['Ticket']['id'], 'userId' => $staffUser['User']['id'])
));
```

My `subscribe` action looks like this:

```
public function subscribe($ticketId, $userId = null){
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //...
    }
}
```

**Update**

---

I've just noticed the provided solution creates another problem to me. Now the `class` stop getting added ulike before when I was using only one parameter:

```
$this->Form->postLink($staffUser['User']['_name'], array(
       'action' => 'subscribe', 
       $ticket['Ticket']['id'], 
       $staffUser['User']['id'],
       array('class' => 'demo') //not beind added
));
```

Comment: Try leaving it blank. If the user is already on /controller/subscribe/TICKETID then it should default to that same URL to POST to (I haven't used postLink but the create() method of FormHelper behaves the same way). If not, then you could also try putting it as a plain string in the second argument, i.e. '/controller/subscribe/param1/param2'.

Comment: I need both paramters. The user Id can be any user id. If its empty, the logged user will subscribe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

postLink takes its URL entry in the same form as the create method. Parameters don't need a key, put them in order after the action key/value.

Other options need to go in the third argument - you have the options array as an additional entry to the url array.

```
$this->Form->postLink($staffUser['User']['_name'], array(
       'action' => 'subscribe', 
       $ticket['Ticket']['id'], 
       $staffUser['User']['id']
    ),
    array(
      'class' => 'demo'
    )
);
```

See options for FormHelper::create here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Comment: Now I have a problem with that. Whenever I pass a `class` it doesn't get added unlike before.

`$this->Form->postLink($staffUser['User']['_name'], array(
       'action' => 'subscribe', 
       $ticket['Ticket']['id'], 
       $staffUser['User']['id'], array('class' => 'demo')
));`

Comment: Updated answer. You have to put the $options array as the third argument to the postLink call - in your example the $options array is an additional entry in the url array.